# Bootstrapping a Mocha test suite

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have numerous tests spread across multiple files in a Node JS application.  I'd like to run bootstrap code prior to Mocha's execution of any of the test files.  This is so that I can, for example, set globals to be used in each of the actual tests.

### Sample bootstrap code

```
global.chai = require('chai');
global.expect = chai.expect;
global.sinon = require('sinon');
```

It seems Mocha loads all files under /test alphabetically, so if I name this bootstrap code "bootstrap.js" and everything else with a starting letter after "B" it "works".

Obviously this is fragile and sucky, but I don't want to put this boilerplate requiring of my supporting libraries at the top of every test file.

How do I tell Mocha to load a bootstrap script first, or create something functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

have you tried `mocha --require mymodule.js TESTS_DIR`

from the documentation

> -r, --require
>
> The --require option is useful for libraries such as should.js, so you
>   may simply --require should instead of manually invoking
>   require('should') within each test file. Note that this works well for
>   should as it augments Object.prototype, however if you wish to access
>   a module's exports you will have to require them, for example var
>   should = require('should').

you could also write at the top of each test to load the `require("./bootstrap.js")` and run tests.

Comment: I am aware of the require option.  It falls a bit short in that it doesn't allow for the parts of the bootstrap that require actual code (rather than just definition).  An example is the above `global.expect = chai.expect` or `chai.use(sinonChai)` or really anything that isn't a require line.  Requiring bootstrap at the top isn't a bad option, just unfortunate for all the same reasons.

Comment: Seems I was under the impression that the require flag only worked for node_modules.  You can actually require in anything, including that bootstrap script.  So, that works!  Yay.  `mocha -r tests/bootstrap.js ...`

Answer (score 3):

I use mocha's flag --delay

> If you need to perform asynchronous operations before any of your
>   suites are run, you may delay the root suite. Simply run Mocha with
>   the --delay flag. This will provide a special function, run(), in the
>   global context.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // do some setup

    describe('my suite', function() {
        // ...
    });

    run();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to use this in TypeScript? Where should we import from or declare the `run` function?

Comment: **Update**: nevermind, it's imported automatically with [@types/mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mocha).

Answer (score 0):

If prior to running Mocha you want to first run some bootstrap code in a file that uses ECMAScript 2015 Module syntax (i.e. `import` instead of `require`)

- Create the following files:

**./setupBabel.js** (to bootstrap Babel transpiler)

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('babel-register');
```

**./setupDependencies.js** (to bootstrap Chai and Sinon using ES2015 syntax)

```
import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
global.expect = chai.expect;
global.sinon = sinon;
```

**./test/codeSpec.js** (example Unit Test using Chai, Sinon Stubs, Spies, and ES2015 syntax such as arrow functions, `let`, and `const`)

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  it('does not modify immutable constant value', () => {
    const myStub = sinon.stub();
    const mySpy = sinon.spy(myStub);
    myStub.returns({});
    let val = 1;
    expect(val).to.not.equal(2);
    sinon.assert.notCalled(mySpy);
  });
});
```

- Run the following in terminal to install relevant NPM packages:

`npm install babel-polyfill babel-register chai sinon mocha`

- Run the test suite with the following terminal command and flags:

`mocha --require ./setupBabel.js --require ./setupDependencies.js ./test/codeSpec.js`

Answer (score -2):

```
describe('异步钩子测试', function () {

  const lover = {
    bodyname: 'yueyue',
    girlname: 'fangfang'
  }

  const test = 'lihang'

  beforeEach('每一个测试之前的钩子', function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('通过')
      })
    })
  })

  it('方方爱张越', function () {
    // 是否等于yueuyue
    expect(lover.bodyname).to.equal('yueyue')

    // 是否是一个字符串
    lover.girlname.should.equal('fangfang')
  })
})
```

Comment: Please tell something more about your solution

Comment: [Please only use English on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).